# Netsuite report shows wrong quantity of good purchased in a pending bills report

Tags: report, netsuite

it seems to add 2 to the number of goods purchased, when I look into the bill in question the quantity is correct. It happens to every bill for unexplained reasons. Just in case it's relevant, these are all dropshipping items. My bandaid solution was to add a field to the purchase order that has value 2 and subtract it from the quantity. However, I'd be interested to know if there is a more elegant solution and why it's happening

Comment: It's showing 2 extra no matter what quantity? Or is it multiplying by 2? On any item? What unit of measure do you use for those items? And what is the corresponding conversion rate for the unit of measure? As the report probably show the quantity in base units.

Comment: yup, no matter what the quantity of the item is it inexplicably adds 2 to it, all items are measured in liters so 10000 becomes 10002, I'm not sure what the conversion to base units would be or where to find it

Comment: In that case, it won't be related to the unit of measure. If you haven't yet, check the quantity column in the report, whether is a calculated column which maybe adds the 2 pcs by default. If all is correct on that side, I would open a new support ticket at NetSuite.